# Windows 10 PersonalizationCSP lock screen wallpaper appears in the settings but not on the actual lock screen

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I'm trying to automate a rotation of my lock screen wallpaper by using the following registry key :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP]
"LockScreenImageStatus"=dword:00000001
"LockScreenImagePath"="*somepath*\\lockscreen.jpg"
"LockScreenImageUrl"="*somepath*\\lockscreen.jpg"
```

At this point, the image I want appears as it should in the settings app :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iit8x.jpg

However, when I actually lock my screen, there's no picture to be seen, I only get a blue-ish background : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT4tb.jpg

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g0UO.jpg) is the picture, if it can help. I naturally tried with several other ones, of different sources. It bore no success.

Edit : I have Windows 10 1909 build 18363.900

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !!

Windows (10 definitly, don't know about previous builds) stores the lock screen wallpapers in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\` and some subfolders in there. By default, no user has access to this directory, not even read-only access.

For a previous tweak, I changed the permissions in there and, by error, I removed all permissions for the system user. That was why the lock screen wallpaper could not be set properly and only appeared in the settings.

I reset the permissions with the command `icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData" /reset /t /c /l` and everything went back to normal.